# How to show a loader image while a page loads slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, pageload

I have db query in my page which fetches a lot of data at time and shows it on the page. FYI, I can not use pagination. So I just want to show a loader image till the time the query fetches all the data and show on the UI. I have tried this code for example, but its not working,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    })
    </script>
     <style>
        .loader {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 9999;
            background: url('processing.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
        }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div class="loader"></div>
        <cfquery datasource="dsn_spinlife_prod_new" name="qryGetProdList">
            SELECT  *
            FROM    tbl_products;
        </cfquery>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But its not working , still firefox show a blank white page while the page loads.I have tried with document.ready also, not working. I want the loader image to be shown , How it can be done, I think i am missing something .

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely that the browser doesn't even get your page until all the slow DB work has been done. You could try putting a `<cfflush>` into the script above after your loader div. That'll cause CF to send back everything generated up to that point back to the browser at that point.

Bear in mind that once you've called `<cfflush>` you can no longer set cookies or send redirects, so you'll want to examine your code to ensure that there's none of that later on in the code.

The other approach would be to generate a page with nothing but a placeholder in it and use jQuery to load in the results as a separate request:

```
<script>
$('#results').load('results.cfm',function(){$('.loader').hide()});
</script>
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Where results.cfm runs the query and generates the HTML necessary to complete the page.

Comment: I would go with just one div.  Start by putting in the image and then use cfflush.  When the rest of the code has ran, use javascript to change the contents of the div.